# Is there any way to export JS variables within a module function to another file using vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript, module, es6-modules

My header.js dynamically creates the buttons that show and hide my pages. These pages are each modulated independently in their own JS files. How can I export the elements' variables that I must change the classList on since I cannot change the classList on a function?

**header.js**

```
function header() {
  const element = document.createElement('div');

  element.innerHTML = `
    <nav>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" id="home"><a href="">Home</a></button>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" id="menu"><a href="">Menu</a></button>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" id="location"><a href="">Location</a></button>
     </nav>
    `;

  // Add the image to our existing div.
  const myIcon = new Image();
  myIcon.src = Icon;
  element.appendChild(myIcon);
  return element;

}

document.body.appendChild(header());

export default header;
```

**Example of my modules
mission.js**

```
const mission = () => {
  const element = document.createElement('div');
  element.classList.add('hide');
  element.innerHTML = `
  <div class='asl'>
      <div class='mission' id='mission'>
          <div class='text-content'>
              <h2>Our Mission</h2>
              <h4>Provide you with Handpicked, Artisanally Curated, Free Range, Sustainable, Organic Tea & Delicious Desserts</h4>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
    `;

  return element;
};

document.body.appendChild(mission());

export default mission;
```

Appreciate your help :)

Comment: There's no such thing as "vanilla JS", only "JS as run in Chrome version X", "JS as run in Node version Y", etc.  Officially the import/export syntax is a part of the "vanilla" JS spec, but the place that the code is run is what really determines whether it is supported or not. 
 So ... where are you trying to run this code?

Comment: Sorry, I only used "Vanilla" so people don't start giving me jQuery, React... answers. If I understand your question correctly, I am trying to write the code to 'unhide' the elements in my index.js. The entry point of my webpack.

Comment: "*since I cannot change the classList on a function*" - why are you using a function at all? How do you expect to deal with the function being called multiple times?

Answer (score 1):

You can export variables; however, your constant is declared in the function and a constant is block-scoped, so it won't be accessible outside of the function brackets.

However, you could use something like the module pattern to export a variable:

```
const myModule = (function() {
const myVariable = 1;

function myFunction() {
return myVariable + 1;
}

function getmyVariable() {
return myVariable;
}

return {myFunction, getMyVariable};
}());

export { myModule };
```

Then you could use it like this:

```
//import it
const variable = myModule.getMyVariable();
```

There are also many more ways you could do this, declare the constant outside the function block, create classes with getters and setters or create Factory Functions.

Answer (score 0):

ES Modules (ie. the `import`/`export` syntax) are a part of the Javascript specification, which is to say, they are "vanilla".

However, that doesn't mean every browser or other JS runtime supports them, and in fact some still don't, or only do in some provisional way.  The [MDN's Modules page](http://mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) has a chart that shows a breakdown of support for popular JS runtimes.

If your runtime *doesn't* support ES Modules, it might support the older CommonJS (ie. `require`) syntax instead.  If it doesn't support either, you will need to use some sort of bundling program.

P.S. One other thing to consider is timing.  When module code runs it runs at load time ... but the DOM might not be ready then, which means `document`-using code may not work.  You have to add the code to some sort of `DOMContentReady` or similar event handler to ensure that the modules load first, *then* the DOM loads, *then* that code runs.

Comment: Thanks. I am using webpack & my browser is a recent Chrome. So, the problem is, I don't know if it is possible to export a variable to my index.js, the entry point to my webpack, and change their classList change them to hide or show them. I do have the whole code in GitHub, but I don't know if I am allowed to use the repository address here. StackOverflow has a lot of detailed regulations on what we can share here.

Comment: Webpack absolutely has support for ES Modules; see: https://webpack.js.org/guides/ecma-script-modules/